# TV series, a blonde lady talks every day with a stranger on the phone

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I can't remember a TV show that I watched almost 10 years ago. A woman dials a wrong number, but after that she talks the man every day.

I guess it was about 10-15 episodes, but I don't remember a lot about the show.

The woman was blonde as I can remember and she has a colleague who has cancer. She was about to get married so her friends don't like her phone calls.

> In the final episode the man on the phone comes to stop the wedding but it wasn't the blonde's wedding. And that's the end.

It was American (unless it was British). I suppose it was a romantic comedy.

Here some other details as I can remember:

The friend who has cancer decides to have a baby and she looks for a father, she needs to choose a guy one of them is the blonde's fiance and the other man is one of her colleagues, she tests two men's strength & abilities.

The main character and theme is the blonde and her phone calls with a stranger. First she accidently calls but then she speaks with him about her life, her day, her problems etc.

And she attends a course or something like that, the course is about money, how you spend, what can you do better with your money (or maybe I'm all making this up). And there was a quote like: "Today people can talk about their relations, sexual lifes, but they can't talk about money."

Comment: Hi. Was it American? Was it a comedy? Drama?

Comment: Hi. Yes it was American (unless it was British). I guess it was romantic comedy.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds vaguely familiar, but maybe I'm just remembering certain aspects of *Gavin & Stacey*.

Comment: I'm hopeless it seems like I need to check all TV shows of 2000s :)

Comment: No worries, I found it. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [Side Order of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_Order_of_Life) that ran for a single 13-episode season on Lifetime in 2007.

> Marisa Coughlan plays Jenny McIntyre, a photographer who reconsiders her life and is reawakened to her options after her best friend, Vivy Porter (Diana-Maria Riva), is diagnosed with a recurrence of cancer. Jason Priestley returns to regular series television as Ian Denison, Jenny's fiance.

After dialing the wrong number, she starts talking to a mystery man  (Steven Weber) over the phone, and in the final episode he rushes to stop her wedding only to realize it isn't *her* wedding. The trailer:

Comment: Thankss, I was about to think that I was mixing TV shows. 

How can you find it? I have googled all combinations of my clues :D